# adodb and access changing ® to Â®

Tags: php, ms-access, adodb

i connecting to a access database with php and adodb. Strings with characters like ® are saved in the database as Â® . 
What can i do to store it correctly?

Comment: Are you updating your database through recordsets (as "rs.update") or through command texts (as "INSERT INTO ...")?

Comment: I'm updating with command texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're passing in a UTF8 string but you're not storing it as UTF8.  Change it one way or the other so they match up (preferably change your database to UTF8).

Comment: Ok, but i didn't find a way to store it as utf8. The connection string is allready with charset=utf8
"DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=something.mdb;UID=Administrator;Charset=utf8" and i didn't find any possibility in adodb to change the storing charset for access databases.

Answer (score 0):

@RoBOrg: Yes, but i didn't find a way to store it as utf8. The connection string is allready with charset=utf8 "DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=something.mdb;UID=Administrator;Charset=utf8" and i didn't find any possibility in adodb to change the storing charset for access databases. 
I'm updating with command text. 
(I sent this as comment before, sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

If you update with command texts, I would have a look at the way the commandText property of your connection is elaborated. I bet that your character update is done even before the INSERT/UPDATE string is sent to the database.